# What muscles would benefit from walking with a boulder cradled in both arms?

Tags: exercise

This seems to have been a very common exercise in ancient civilizations.

What muscle groups would benefit from this? I'd be surprised if this is a really effective workout, but I'm not against it.

Comment: What size? How is it being held?

Comment: I clarified—it is being cradled. The weight isn't necessarily relevant, but let's say an 80 lbs. boulder, cradled, proportioned to a person weighing 130 lbs. Scale it as needed.

Comment: "I'd be surprised if this is a really effective workout" - It's not *meant* to be a workout. It's an exercise. It's *part* of a workout.

Answer (score 1):

The name is Atlas carry.

The weight doesn't matter, but size and the time spent holding and walking with it.

This exercise builds mainly the trapezius muscles, important postural muscle that keeps your upper back extended and shoulder retracted, its the one muscle you want to build for healthy posture. other muscles focused during this movement are the are the spinal erectors, gluteus medius and either the calf or tibia muscle depending on your walking stile.

Loaded carries carryover to most squatting and deadlifting patterns, even to overhead pressing, but this specially improves the front squat and conventional deadlift.